# Number of Messages on akka-streams Backpressure

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

As well-explained [here thanks to Sean Glover](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/alpakka-kafka-flow-control-optimizations), I have been exploring how backpressure works on Alpakka.

As I see, when mailbox size is not defined, the [default mailbox](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/mailboxes.html#default-mailbox) size is set to be unbounded.

My question is about demand requests that downstream operators send to upstreams. What is the number of messages stand on the demand request with default mailbox on Alpakka? Does the number of messages has a fixed value regardless of mailbox definition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what's meant by "the number of messages stand on the demand request"?

Comment: It's worth remembering that due to stream-operator fusion, the actor mailbox is only relevant at async boundaries.

Comment: I see. When I use mapAsync(n), the n here represents the mailbox size, am I right? For example when I use commitableSource to consume Kafka with mapAsync(n) declared, does it mean that I am using only one actor which can process n number of records at once?

Comment: In the particular case of Alpakka Kafka, there's an actor which interacts with Kafka (among other things, this allows the consumer to stay alive even if the downstream processes messages more slowly than the consumer timeout), so there're implicit async boundaries around the Kafka source and the Kafka sink.  So a `kafkaSource -> processingFlow -> kafkaSink` would have at least two async boundaries.

Comment: Absent `async`s in the `processingFlow` (and `mapAsync` doesn't introduce an `async`: `mapAsync` is not equivalent to `map.async` or `async.map`), `processingFlow` is all one actor.  However, in `mapAsync`, typically you're doing the actual processing in a `Future`: `mapAsync(n)` allows `n` `Future`s to be live without backpressuring.  The actual parallelism you can get depends on how those `Future`s are executed (e.g. on the `ExecutionContext`).